# JAVA char input

Tags: java, io, char

My code is not taking input into a char variable after it takes its first value.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Character;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                                                                                          
        char s;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("->");
            s=(char)br.read();
            System.out.print(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this output

```
->a
->>
```

And i wont this

```
->a
a
->b
b
->c
c
```

Comment: `System.out.print` does not flush by default.

Comment: What does the `read()` javadoc say? How many (and which) characters are entered when you typ `a <Enter>`? What happens when you print the actual integer returned by `read()` instead of printing it as a char?

Comment: ->a
97->13->10     (I am getting this output when i printed it as an integer)

Comment: I used flush and it says "char cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: So, what do you conclude? When you google for "ascii table" and look what the characters 13 and 10 are, what do you obtain as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Java Docs: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read())

read() function reads a single character at a time.

Input Provided : a followed by Enter.

br.read() reads following characters in iteration: a -> \r -> \n
in the first three iterations. If you loop over for more than 3, it would again prompt for user input.

You can approach your problem by following two ways:

1. Using read() function : In this case, input needs to be like 'abcd' instead of 'a', then 'b', then 'c' then 'd'.

```
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
           {
               BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                                                                                          
               char s;
               for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
               {
                   System.out.print("->");
                   s=(char)br.read();
                   System.out.print(s);
               }
           }
```

2. Using readLine() function: Input would be the way mentioned in question.

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
            {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                                                                                          
                String s;
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("->");
                    s=br.readLine();
                    System.out.print(s);
                }
            }
```

Comment: *After, you press 'Enter', input stream ends*. No, not at all.

Comment: @JBNizet, got your point. made changes to the answer. please correct me if anything still is off. Thanks again for pointing out.